# reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith works fine on Tomcat but not Weblogic

Tags: java, reflection, weblogic

My application runs fine on Tomcat but on Weblogic one of the dependencies (http://jsondb.io/) is failing. 
JsonDB internally calls

```
reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Document.class);
```

to get all the classes I annotated with @Document annotation

As per title: the same WAR file works fine on Tomcat, but when deployed to Weblogic my classes are not detected and API calls fail.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: it looks like a problem with runtime dependencies in weblogic rather than a problem with reflection.

Comment: @piradian jsondb loads and executes fine, reflections returns an empty set of classes instead of a couple of classes that get returned when running under Tomcat. Are there any specific steps for me to include my  project files in classpath for weblogic?

Comment: unfortunately I do not know anything special :(. How your deplyment configuration looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by adding the following to weblogic.xml

```
<container-descriptor>
    <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
</container-descriptor>
```